# Is there any way to export a database using MYSQL Command Line Client?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to export a **MySQL** database using **MYSQL Command Line Client**?

I have a database named as **naukri_portal**, which contains 3 tables. I am trying to export the database using **MYSQL Command Line Client** but it didn't work.

```sql
mysqldump -u root -p naukri_portal > naukri_portal.sql
```

Comment: Not working means? what error you got? From which location you executed script? Any screenshots?

Comment: Now, it's working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this command which will ask for a password and download your database into the current directory

```
 mysqldump -u root -p database> dump.sql
```

if you are form windows use PowerShell administrator mode and if you are using Linux use Sudo command. Then run those query.

You can also follow below steps

**Step -1** First download SQLyog https://sqlyog.jaleco.com/, then install it.

You will get something like [image]
Now create a new connection for your localhost then connect to your remote database. You must remain connected to both servers together.

**Step -2** Then right-click to your remote database you will get the following options. 
[image]

**step-3** Now click copy database to a different host then you will get another window like
 [image]

**step-4** Finally, select localhost and your database from the dropdown option. If you want structure and data check below option. Then click copy. The database will be copied. Due to my old version interface could be different but process will remain the same.

Comment: actually, I want to use the database from one system to another. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean my one system to another system would you elaborate please

Comment: I have a database which contains some tables, now I want to use that database to my laptop, or you can say I want an exact replica of my database into my laptop. So how can I do that in SQL workbench we can export the database and it generates a SQL file which we can execute in another system and the database with tables is generated?

Comment: You can use SQLyog which will connect with both of your databases then you can simply copy your remote database into a local database.

Comment: Or in simple term, I want to export my database to a SQL file. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm updating my answer check that

Comment: ok, sure I will.

Comment: Try the 2nd process will be easier for you

Comment: Please give upvote if it helps

Comment: I tried the above query but it says, access is denied.

Comment: what kind of system you are using?? windown or linux

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: Search for Powershell in your windows then right-click on it then select run as an aminstrator, then run ``mysqldump -u root -p databaseName> dump.sql``.  Your mysql password will be asked, just give that password then sql will be dumped into your current directory

Comment: Thanks, I tried the above snippet and it works.

Comment: Then please accept my answer